# HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync results in null on the API and PostAsync works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor

For some reason PostAsJsonAsync doesn't work:

Blazor Client (.Net Core 3.1):

```
    var item = new TodoItem() { Name = "1111111" };

    var client1 = new HttpClient();
    await client1.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:64400/api/test/", item);

    var client2 = new HttpClient();
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    await client2.PostAsync("http://localhost:64400/api/test/", content);
```

API (.NET 4.8)

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(TodoItem model)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

client1 call results in model being null and for client1 call a proper model can be seen on the API. When I run Fiddle, both calls are identical and repeating client1 call actually results in a proper model seen on the API.

When I examine the raw request of client1 in Fiddler, I do see some weird characters

```
POST http://localhost:64400/api/test/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:64400
Request-Id: |4bde91df-41c09eb19a740271.
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

2C
{"Id":0,"Name":"1111111","IsComplete":false}
0
```

2C and 0 don't seem like they should be there? What is going on?

Edit: the culprit is `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and for some reason `client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = false;` doesn't work

Comment: Transfer-Encoding: chunked (check section 3.6 of RFC 2616)... 2C is size

Comment: @Selvin got it thanks. Still 1. Why PostAsJsonAsync by default uses it and 2. Why can't API process it?

Comment: I guess is because `PostAsJsonAsync` does serialization on fly on background thread (so it will save memory)

Comment: I think the situation called for `TransferEncodingChunked = true;` because the client uses it and the API should know that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman is this a bug? Why Web API can't figure out chunked content? And how to prevent HttpClient to send chunked request?